# "Unfortunately, Email has stopped" on Samsung phone when adding SPAM to filter

Tags: email, samsung, crashes

I have been tracking this issue for a while and noone seems to have a good solution.

examples:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/409389-unfortunately-email-has-stopped.html
http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/401360-email-spam-limit.html

The error is: "Unfortunately, Email has stopped"

The cause seems to be that Samsung's default/stock email app has a 200 item limit for it's SPAM filter.

This error affects Galaxy Note 2 and Note 3, and Galaxy S4 (probably more)

- I am looking for a way to make this limit bigger.